# What is the meaning of '.?select=*.xml;recurse=yes' in xslt string?

Tags: xslt

I've seen Michael Kay kindly respond to XSL questions with a template something like shown below.

I'm wondering where the syntax for the string being passed to `collection()` is documented? I tried searching the XSL spec for some sort of wildcard pattern with recursion but came up empty.

```
<xsl:template name="main">
  <xsl:for-each select="collection('.?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')">
    <xsl:result-document href="out/{tokenize(document-uri(.), '/')[last()]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: See the Saxon documentation on collections: http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/sourcedocs/collections.html. The argument of that function is a URI and how that is interpreted is up to the particular XSLT/XPath/XQuery implementation you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Martin's link, it appears this special behavior is native to `StandardCollectionURIResolver` in *Saxon* which interprets `?select=*.xml;recurse=yes` as a query string where `select` provides file globbing and `recurse` provides automatic directory recursion.

Comment: That's correct. (Actually from 9.7 it's the StandardCollectionFinder which is a lot more powerful, supporting the 3.0 ability for collections to contain resources of any media type, not just XML documents).